# Redirect image links to corresponding blog post

Tags: html, hyperlink

so I found this code in the HTML structure of my blog template:

```
<a href="'+img[0].src+'"
```

Im assuming it controls the redirection of the link when an image is clicked on the homepage of my blog. Is there a way I can modify this piece of code to make it so that the image link redirects to the post it is associated with?

Thanks!!

Comment: <a href="http://www.yourwebsite.com/where-your-post-resides/">Link To Post</a>

Comment: So, I'm guessing that clicking on the link simply opens that image in the browser? What platform are you using?

Comment: That line would just redirect all image links to one specific post.  Exactly Todd, I'm on blogger at the moment, sadly